# Watir webdriver: Doesn't do anything after opening browser (firefox)

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

It was working fine before, now whenever I run the script it just opens Firefox then does nothing. It works when running with chromedriver though.

Tried updating gems etc, but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest Firefox version will no longer work with the legacy Firefox Driver. To use Watir with Firefox 48+ you need to download [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and [follow the instructions for Ruby](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver).

Since Geckodriver is not yet feature complete, you most likely will want to continue using the legacy Firefox Driver, which means either using [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) or downgrading to Firefox 47.0.1.

Comment: Thanks man, it was the firefox verison... downgrading solved it.