# Watir: Trouble with if statements

Tags: ruby, watir

I spent a while looking but didn't find anything that helped much, so I decided to ask myself.

Anyways, I'm trying to make a **non-malicious** bot to respond to certain forum threads on a forum. However, I'm stuck on making an if statement that will detect if a thread has a certain name, and click on that thread if it does. This is what the closest I've come:

```
def Replies()
  while true
    $browser.div(:text => ':HexBot/Summon')
    sleep(5)
    $browser.goto <insert link here. i didn't include it for privacy reasons>
  end
end
```

What this *should* do is refresh the page every 5 seconds. If it sees a thread saying ':HexBot/Summon' then it would click on that thread. However. I just get an error. I tried doing this entirely without if statements, but that also gave me an error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understand the question, so let me know if this isn't what you are asking for:

```
def Replies()
  until $browser.div(:text => ':HexBot/Summon').present?
    sleep(5)
    $browser.goto <insert link here>
  end
  $browser.div(:text => ':HexBot/Summon').click
end
```

That should reload the page every 5 seconds (forever) until the desired text appears, at which point the text will be clicked. You could also use `$browser.refresh` instead of the `$browser.goto` statement (assuming you start on the correct page).

Lastly, you tagged this question `watir`. I use `watir-webdriver`, and there are some differences, but hopefully what I have offered here works for you.

Comment: Yeah, I use watir instead of watir-webdriver because firefox doesn't want to cooperate with me. Btw, I think this is what I've been looking for, but haven't yet had a chance to test it out. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, from Firefox 48 onward you won't be able to use `watir-webdriver`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185507/watir-webdriver-doesnt-do-anything-after-opening-browser-firefox/39185569#39185569. I hope my method works for you!

Comment: 48+ requires geckodriver. You can use it with `watir-webdriver` by setting `marionette: true` on initialization. Or you can use it with `watir` > v6.0 where it is set to true by default.

Comment: One little problem though. It seems like the until block doesn't want to execute what I actually have written in it. It just doesn't do anything.

Comment: You're saying the page doesn't reload every five seconds? Maybe add in a `puts` statement for debugging to see that something is actually happening?