# Watir Timeout issue with Firefox

Tags: firefox, rubygems, watir, watir-webdriver, rubymine

I am attempting to run the following ruby code via RubyMine:

require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto 'http://www.apple.com'

When I run I get the following error:

firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
    from /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:55:in `block in launch'
    from /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:43:in`locked'
    from /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:51:in `launch'
    from /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:43:in`initialize'
    from /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:53:in `new'
    from /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:53:in`for'
    from /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:84:in `for'
    from /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.3/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in`initialize'
    from /Users/mark/cheezy/first_script.rb:3:in `new'
    from /Users/mark/cheezy/first_script.rb:3:in`'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in`'

I have the latest Watir-Webdriver gem installed .

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watir webdriver: Doesn't do anything after opening browser (firefox)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185507/watir-webdriver-doesnt-do-anything-after-opening-browser-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox 48+ you need to use geckodriver.
Download from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Selenium instructions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

Watir instructions: http://watir.github.io/watir-6-beta/

Please let me know if you have any further issues.

Comment: Mark, no it's an executable, you need to download it and put it on your path, similar to chromedriver.   
@titusfortner can you perhaps include in your answer an example of how you would set the capabilities so that when you create the new browser object that it properly talks to Marionette ?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have downloaded the geckodriver and added it to my PATH using :export PATH=$PATH:/users/mark/downloads/geckodriver  . I then added the new WATIR gem and then re run my test script. I now get the following error: /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0.beta3.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox.rb:58:in `driver_path':         Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from        https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it        somewhere on your PATH.

Comment: Oh, when I run ECHO $Path I get /Users/mark/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/users/mark/downloads/geckodriver

Comment: It's better practice to move binaries into directories that are already on PATH. I believe Selenium is looking for geckodriver binary in a downloads/geckodriver directory (which doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did as you suggested but now I am getting the following: Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/CHANGES
Using cucumber 2.4.0