# I am unable to run my scripts on firefox

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver, watir-classic

My scripts are not running with firefox and I am using firefox version-49.0.1,  Here is the error Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watir webdriver: Doesn't do anything after opening browser (firefox)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185507/watir-webdriver-doesnt-do-anything-after-opening-browser-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your Firefox to 47.0.1 and try again.

Comment: what is the problem with firefox version-49.0.1

Comment: I tried with firefox version above 49 and selenium v 3. They did not work out. I downgraded my firefox and it worked. It looks like compatibility problem.

Comment: Anytime. If this answer resolved your problem, kindly upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade is an oppertunity but if you want to be sure that your tests run with the newest version of Firefox, you can run the Selenium-RC server [look here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/).
In my case this fixed many compatibility issues. This works with every Firefox, Google Chrome and Internet Explorer version so far. Hower in my opinion your whole project would be ordered better.